# Symfony "No route found"

Tags: php, symfony

I recently built a new symfony-project with one simple controller to read in a .csv file and output it's content to a template.
I generated the bundle and the controller using the console and gave the controller the route "/browse".
When trying to run, (127.0.0.1:8000/browse) it tells me: "No route found for "GET/browse"".

**src/OpiumBundle/Controller/BrowseController.php**

```
<?php

namespace OpiumBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class BrowseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/browse")
     */
    public function indexAction() {
        $varPath = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../var';
        return $this->render('OpiumBundle:Browse:index.html.php', array(
            // ...
        ));
    }

}
```

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
opium:
    resource: "@OpiumBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

unfortunately I can't post output from my debug:console, because my rep is too low. but there are two empty spaces where I guess they shouldn't:

**debug:router**

```
opium_homepage             ANY      ANY      ANY    /                                  
homepage                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /
```

Comment: How did you set the route?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: I set the route in the annotation of the function of my controller.

Comment: clearing the chache did not fix it

Comment: `php bin/console debug:router` - can you see the route here? If not, maybe a typo in the route definition in the controller (please post the controller in the question so we can help you if that is the case)

Comment: Check your `app/AppKernel.php` to ensure the bundle is included in the `$bundles` array. Check `app/config/routing.yml` for the `resource: @Bundle/Controller/` inclusion as `type: annotation` Please update your question with the route from `routing.yml` and the code for your controller `browseAction` including the annotations.

Comment: I added the required info to my main post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the `yml` option while generating a bundle, will result in a  bundle routing.yml file being created with a `Bundle:Default:index` of `bundle_homepage`, and the config file being included as a resource in your app routing.yml file.

Check your `src/OpiumBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` file and ensure it reads as.

```
opium_bundle:
    resource: '@OpiumBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

Alternatively edit your `app/config/routing.yml` file to read

```
opium:
    resource: "@OpiumBundle/Controller/"
    prefix: /
    type: annotation

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

Otherwise you will not be able to utilize annotation based routing and would need to manually add the routes to your `routing.yml` config files.

After making the changes clear your cache

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Check your routes to ensure that `browse` is included

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

Which should output

```
opium_browse_index   ANY   ANY   ANY   /browse
```

Comment: That did it! Thank!

Comment: @AlexanderTepe No problem, be sure to update any of your pre-existing routes to annotations. and please accept the answer to mark the question as answered.

Comment: I am having the same issue..  new to synfony and   netbeans.

Comment: @kiwicomb123 highly suggest you invest into PHPStorm and the Symfony plugin. It makes programming in Symfony much easier with auto-completion, context menu support, etc. Also helps to run through a KNPUniversity tutorial.  https://knpuniversity.com/tracks/symfony3

Comment: I think I will..  I am struggling to get anything going here.